# about frame type (I,P,B) in mpeg-4

Tags: c#, video, mp4, mpeg-4, frameset-iframe

i am working at frames types information in mpeg-4(mp4v\mp4a),and use c# language, found

samples size,number of samples in each chunk , samples description  ,and chunk offset.

i need access to frames types (I, B, P). Do you have any code of how to access them?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show that code. I doubt anyone will do it for you.

Comment: ...and also, I see this is the third time in the last hour you've asked this question. Please don't spam the site, edit your first question instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [find frame type in mpeg-4 file (I,P,B)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469819/find-frame-type-in-mpeg-4-file-i-p-b)